# How to convert the format of a facebook post URL

Tags: facebook, url

I'm using an online program which requires a Facebook post URL. To get the URL, I click the timestamp on the post and it gives me the post url in the following format:

www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=xxxxxxxxxxxx&id=xxxxxxxxxx&stream_ref=10

However, that format is not supported by the program. It needs a URL in this format:

www.facebook.com/myusername/posts/xxxxxxxxxxx

From what I've read, to get the post URL they say click the timestamp to get the URL and they all end up having the URL in the second format which makes me think that something recently changed.

Is there a way to still get the post URL in the second format? Alternatively, is there a way to convert the first URL format to the second?

Comment: I get the second format. So if you paste your URL, maybe I can convert it for you. :)

Comment: you need to get a `username` from https://www.facebook.com/username this will solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the format, it's the following. You must swap the numbers XXXXX and YYYYY from the first URL in the relevant places in the other URL, illustrated below.

www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=XXXXX&id=YYYYY&stream_ref=10

www.facebook.com/YYYYY/posts/XXXXX